# Splitting a string at first number and then returning 2 strings

Tags: c#, arrays, string

Having some trouble adapting my splitting of a string into 2 parts to do it from the first number. It's currently splitting on the first space, but that won't work long term because cities have spaces in them too.

Current code:

```
var string = "Chicago 1234 Anytown, NY"
var commands = parameters.Split(new[] { ' ' }, 2);
var originCity = commands[0];
var destination = commands[1];
```

This works great for a city that has a single name, but I break on:

```
var string = "Los Angeles 1234 Anytown, NY"
```

I've tried several different approaches that I just haven't been able to work out. Any ideas on being able to return 2 strings as the following:

```
originCity = Los Angeles
destination = 1234 Anytown, NY
```

Comment: You should never name your variable `string`. That's a reserved keyword in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `.Split()` for this.

Instead, you need to find the index of the first number. You can use [`.indexOfAny()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexofany(v=vs.110).aspx) with an array of numbers (technically a `char[]` array) to do this.

```
int numberIndex = address.IndexOfAny("0123456789".ToCharArray())
```

You can then capture two [substrings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx); One before the index, the other after.

```
string before = line.Substring(0, numberIndex);
string after = line.Substring(numberIndex);
```

Comment: This worked out perfectly, thanks for pointing at the invalid approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Regex. In the following, match is the first match in the regex results.

```
var match = Regex.Match(s, "[0-9]");
if (match.Success)
{
    int index = match.Index;
    originCity = s.Substring(0, index);
    destination = s.Substring(index, s.Length - index);
}
```

Or you can do it yourself:

```
int index = 0;
foreach (char c in s)
{
    int result;
    if (int.TryParse(c, out result))
    {
        index = result;
        break;
    }
    //or if (char.IsDigit()) { index = int.Parse(c); break; }
 }
 ...
```

Comment: `char.IsDigit` is probably more efficient than `int.TryParse`.

Answer (score -1):

You should see if using a regular expression will do what you need here.  At least with the sample data you're showing, the expression:

```
(\D+)(\d+)(\D+)
```

would group the results into non-numeric characters up to the first numeric character, the numeric characters until a non-numeric is encountered, and then the rest of the non-numeric characters.  Here is how it would be used in code:

```
var pattern = @"(\D+)(\d+)(\D+)"; 
var input = "Los Angeles 1234 Anytown, NY"; 
var result = Regex.Match(input, pattern); 
var city = result.Groups[1]; 
var destination = $"{result.Groups[2]} {result.Groups[3]}";
```

This falls apart in cases like 29 Palms, California or if the numbers would contain comma, decimal, etc so it is certainly not a silver bullet but I don't know your data and it may be ok for such a simple solution.

Comment: How would this split the results the way the OP wanted?

Comment: @Soviut - it solves the problem being posed by the OP by capturing the data into groups that can be consumed:

            var pattern = @"(\D+)(\d+)(\D+)";
            var input = "Los Angeles 1234 Anytown, NY";

            var result = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
            var city = result.Groups[1];
            var destination = $"{result.Groups[2]} {result.Groups[3]}";

reading the question again, though, I would have used a slightly different RegEx and only captured two groups since there is no advantage to splitting the destination into two capture groups